# Firefox extension content page

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on porting a chrome extension to a firefox extension.

The chrome extension has a "index.html" page that loads up in a tab when clicking the extension . Is this possible in a firefox extension?

Comment: The answer is, of course, yes.

Comment: Haha ok thanks. I downloaded the firefox ext sdk and initialized a extension. Theres no html files that it created or anything referring to a "landing page". How do I set this up?

Comment: I seem to have figured it out by adding "tabs.open("index.html");" to main.js and creating index.html in the data folder.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: That sounds like a method that would work for having the tab open when the extension is started (e.g. on load, on install, etc.). You might want to take a look at the [SDK Toutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials).  For example, [Adding a Button to the Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Adding_a_Button_to_the_Toolbar). Those/that should show you how to make the tab open when a button is clicked in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the add-on SDK and adapting the tutorial that is available at [Adding a Button to the Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Adding_a_Button_to_the_Toolbar), the following should do what you have described.

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "my-extension-index-button",
  label: "Open index.html",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("index.html");
}
```